# Вопрос по заполнению Uniformgrid MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть модель и вьюмодель:

```
class model : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int size;
        public int Size
        {
            get { return size; }
            set
            {
                size = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Size");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }

class viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<model> Size { get; set; }

        public viewmodel()
        {
            Size = new ObservableCollection<model>
            {
                new model { Size=9 }
            };
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

Код MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="mvvm4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Path=Size}" Columns="{Binding Path=Size}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Как мне заполнить полностью Uniform grid элементами button или другими?(Т.е. заполнить сетку кнопками размером size на size?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class ButtonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name //надо же хоть что-то сбиндить =)
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

public class MainViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _size;
    public int Size  //Это должно быть на этом уровне, ведь привязка ListBox идет именно к этой вьюмодели, а уже элементы привязываются к элементам коллекции.
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set
        {
            _size= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Size");
        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel> ButtonList{ get; set; }

    public MainViewmodel()
    {
        ButtonList= new ObservableCollection<ButtonViewModel>
        {
            // Нужно побольше, чтоб проверить, надо 81 элемент добавить. так что лучше циклом.
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button1" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button2" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button3" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button4" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button5" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button6" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button7" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button8" },
            new ButtonViewModel { Name="Button9" },
        };
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
```

Xaml таков.

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ButtonList}"> 
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Path=Size}" Columns="{Binding Path=Size}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
              <Button Content="{Binding Name}"></Button> 
            </Grid>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Comment: спасибо, а как исправить?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вы хотите заполнить сетку 9 на 9?

Comment: да, правильно поняли

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас изменю ответ.

Comment: Всё, код проверил - рабочий.

Comment: спасибо, а если я хочу менять размер сетки то что делать?

Comment: Очевидно, менять поле `Size` (в коде не отображено, но при создании вьюмодели надо указывать ее, а то по-умолчанию `0` `UniformGrid` игнорирует и располагает элементы как хочет), если хочется сетку неправильной формы (3*5) например, вместо одного поля сделать два `Row` и `Column` например - и их биндить.

Comment: @Draktharon Вопрос то закройте уже приняв ответ.